# Uninstalling VisualSVN 2.0 from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visualsvn

Is there a way to uninstall VisualSVN 2.0 from Visual Studio 2010? 
There is no uninstaller in the Control Panel and I can't find it to remove it in Visual Studio 2010.

Is the only option just to remove the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From VS: Tools->Extension Manager->Visual SVN->Uninstall

Answer (score 14):

From VS:

```
Tools->Extension Manager->Visual SVN->Uninstall .
```

In visual studio 2010, Uninstall button is disabled. If disabled, go [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/) and install the visual svn again. During installation, you will get an remove option. Click the 'Remove' button. It will remove Visual SVN form visual studio.

Do forget to Restart the visual studio.

Comment: A double +1 for the Uninstall via the .msi tip.

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2010, the Uninstall button is disabled.

I definitely don't want to upgrade VisualSVN (per @Md. Tahmilur Rahman above) just so I can remove it from Visual Studio. Going to Control Panel/Uninstall a program/VisualSVN and removing it also cleared it out of VS2010 the next time I opened it.

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was still visible in add/remove programs (start>run>appwiz.cpl) and uninstall was available there

Answer (score 2):

Actually, neither of these solutions worked, since my ability to uninstall via the Extension Manager was disabled and VisualSVN didn't appear in my list of programs through the Control Panel.  Even after using Revo Uninstaller to reveal it in my list of Programs, uninstalling it failed.

After a bit more research, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646936/how-to-manually-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2010-extension).  Essentially, you have to run VS2010 as administrator (right click application icon, then choose "Run as Administrator").  Only then will the Uninstall button appear in the Extension Manager so you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall it by running the installer from VisualSVN again, and selecting the remove option.

Comment: Isn't this already included in the answer by Md. Tahmilur Rahman?